# NUnit test fails in TeamCity but passes locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, nunit, teamcity

The test is for our REST API that it returns a bad request if we try to pass missing information to the POST.

As said in title, this works fine locally, it also looks like it's fine when you look at the build log in Team City...

```
JetBrains.TeamCity.PlatformProcessRunner.v4.0.msil.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=400 (BadRequest), Method=POST, Url=http://localhost:7447/api/letters, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
```

But it's showing as a failure and that build step fails :(

The only mention of error I can find in the stack trace is...

```
------- Stderr: -------
JetBrains.TeamCity.PlatformProcessRunner.v4.0.msil.exe Information: 0 :
```

That's it.. I'm at a total loss as to what's going wrong here and what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was asp.net API issue. We had the following config being enabled for our unit test projects.

```
Config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
```

Unfortunately this causes TeamCity to register an error after each test (maybe because we aren’t responding with a 200 status code, but I haven’t tested this bit) with no error information. 
Removed this line and it fixed the problem.